# Make content div and top/bottom running marginals equal 100% total height?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Ok so I've got a header and a footer with absolute positioning and heights of 144px. The content div in the middle area needs to be the full height of the area in between.

Simplified:

```
<style>
  .marginals{
    position: absolute;
    height: 144px; 
    width: 100%; 
    left: 0;
  }
  #header{ top:    0px; }
  #footer{ bottom: 0px; }
</style>

<div id="header" class="marginals"></div>
<div id="content"> Content </div>
<div id="footer" class="marginals"></div>
```

So basically I want a div that is 100% - 288px. At first I thought I could just make a 100% x 100% div with 144 padding on top and bottom and then stuff the content div in there at 100% but my thinking has gone stray somewhere.

[image]

> Here's an example I made using 20% height for 'bread layers'. (Which I can't do on this project) Used 60% height for the scrolling 'meaty layer' and put it at top: 20%;

Comment: Cross linking to [English.SE question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24060/what-word-defines-a-category-suited-for-both-header-and-footer) about header & footer which spawned from originally naming the class 'sandwich' instead of 'marginals' (I like running marginals..but it is kinda long for code :P )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have won't work, tables and absolute positioning don't go well together, and height on table rows and cells is not handled consistently across browser anyway so I think you'd find it hard to get the top/bottom rows to stay a fixed height while still asking the middle row to scroll

however I think you were right with your original posting and using absolute positioning, you don't need percentages though, you can use the top and bottom co-ordinates tohether, so you can tell the middle div to start at 144px from top and finish 144px from bottom..

e.g.

**HTML:**

```
   <div class="header">Some header content</div>

   <div class="wrap">
   Bulk content<br>bulk content<br>bulk content<br>bulk content<br>
   Bulk content<br>bulk content<br>bulk content<br>bulk content
   </div>

   <div class="footer">Some footer content</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;}

.wrap { 
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 144px; /* = height of header including any borders or padding */
  bottom: 144px; /* = height of footer including any borders or padding */
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
}

.header, .footer {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 0;
height: 140px;
background: #f00;
}

.header {
top: 0;
border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
}

.footer {
bottom: 0;
border-top: 4px solid #000;
}
```

The whole thing is based on the `html, body` elements having the height of 100% set

#### Example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/d5d4X/)

Comment: Can you expand a little on the mechanics here? I had no idea specifying 2 positions would matter like that! Is it just that `bottom: NUMpx;` needs a defined height for html, body to work this way?

Comment: yes, will only work if you know the height of the top and bottom parts, then specifying the top and bottom position of the middle section to match them will take up the available height between then, then you can use `overflow` on it just as if it had am explicit height too.. the 100% height on the html/body makes the whole screen available for the absolute positioning to take it's position from.. body is the default root element for AP elements to be relative to, and it won't be 100% if html is not 100% - so that's the start of the 'chain' ;)

Comment: you may want to edit your answer as I've turned this into my better question. this one with the tables really irked me..

Comment: @Garet Claborn, interesting discussion over there on EL&U :) but I think I'll leave the answer, as it reflects the question as asked. In the coding world, everyone knows what a header/footer is and in CSS the grouping of the class/ID names, instead of adding another class/ID, is a feature. In the above example it just so happens the header/footer have quite a few features in common but that may not always be the case and you would need to know that at the time of coding the HTML in order to add the "marginals" class, which would go against the separation of presentation from content ethos

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to create a 3 liquid row-layout. Why not try something like this:

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/jCjsD/2/

---

### HTML

```
<body>

<div id="body_container">
    <div id="header">Some header content</div>
    <div id="content"><!-- Bulk content here !--></div>
</div>

<div id="footer">Footer</div>

</body>
```

### CSS

```
#header, #content, #footer {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
    background: yellow;
}

#footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #888;
    background: yellow;
}

#content {
    clear: both;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -50px;
    height: 50px;
    clear:both;
}   

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#body_container {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```